# Can I read FB API information in offline mode?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I know FB allows offline mode, but how to work it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When getting access permissions from a user to login to your app via facebook, you need to ask permission for offline access in your API call. The auth token that you get back from FB has an expiry on it - if the user gives you offline access permissions, that expiry time is set to be infinite.

For more info on offline access, refer: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/ (see section under Write Permissions)